# Why Won't the WP7 Developer Tools Install Correctly for Expression Blend

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

When I install the Windows Phone Developer Tools, the installation appears to be successful, and they work great in VS2010 (SP1) meaning that I have the phone templates and I can launch an app in the emulator or on my device. But it's not installing correctly in Blend. I have no phone templates, I can't launch my app in the emulator or on the devices and furthermore, the phone resources (like PhoneTextNormalStyle, etc.) are red squiggly underlined in the XAML pages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed a very old version of the Windows Phone Developer Tools. See [Expression Blend's Getting Started](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986096%28Expression.40%29) page on details on how to get started with the SDK.

Mind you, it's only available for Expression Studio 4.

Comment: No, I installed the latest off of the MSDN website. And this is Expression Studio 4 I have.

Comment: Re-install the Developer Tools then.

Comment: I have and it doesn't work. For troubleshooting, I installed on another machine and saw that it correctly installs projects in Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Blend 4\ProjectTemplates\en\CSharp. On my primary laptop, it doesn't get those templates.

Comment: Try uninstall Silverlight 4, and any other leftover SDK you might have related to Silverlight, before installing the SDK. There used to be a bug, and even though I'm sure it's been fixed, it's worth a try.

Comment: Dang. I just went for the gold and uninstalled everything development related... VS2010, Expression Studio, all SDKs, all .NET frameworks, etc. Then I reinstalled .NET 4, then Expression Studio, then the phone tools. Same thing. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: You could always copy over the templates manually. But indeed, it sounds strange.

Comment: Yeah, and surely that would give me the templates, but there's also the matter of the emulator and resources not working. I decided I'd pave the system this weekend, so that had better do it :) Thanks for you help Claus!